# Select from table

Tags: php, mysql

Just before I had form, from which the code will receive Nr1 and Nr2, I also already had created a table(Nr, x, y, z). Now I need to find value x in the table, where Nr is equal to Nr1.
I receive correct echo $Nr1, but receive no $x1, which means mistake is in mysql_query. Please help me find it. Thank you.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['addy']))
    {
        $con=mysqli_connect("***","***","***","****");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "No MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
        $Nr1 = $_POST['Nr1'];
        $Nr2 = $_POST['Nr2'];
        echo $Nr1;
        $x1 = mysql_query("SELECT `x` FROM `table` WHERE `Nr`='$Nr1'");
        echo $x1;
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Echoing the result of `mysql_query` is *NOT* going to give you the row(s) it found.  You need to `fetch` the rows from the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
$x1 = mysql_query("SELECT `x` FROM `table` WHERE `Nr`='$Nr1'");
```

The output is not a string! To get the resulsts, make a while loop:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($x1)){
echo $row['RowNr1'];
echo ' - ';
echo $row['RowNr2'];
echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Also, use mysqli_error if you think you've a mistake in your SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Change to because the return `$x1` is boolean.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `x` FROM `table` WHERE `Nr`='$Nr1'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
echo $row['x'];
```

Documentation: [mysql_fetch_array](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

**mysql_*** functions is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.